# iOS Safari focus on element at the bottom of the page issue

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have an issue with iOS Safari. There is no such issue in Chrome browser.

When focus on the element at the end of a page, keyboard appears and a part of body background is become visible. Has anyone encountered this problem?

HTML Code:

```css
html, body{
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/GrxcU65.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <select id="test">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Safari screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/59khX.jpg